# Out-of-date state using state monad

Tags: haskell

Here's a function `runGame` using the state monad:

```
runGame = do
    state <- get
    addPoints
    let newState = ...modify state in some way...
    put newState
```

1. I get the state
2. I modify it
3. I put the new state.

Now suppose I modify the state in `addPoints` too:

```
addPoints = do
  modify (+1)
```

The problem is, the state I have in `runGame` is out of date now. So when I modify that state and put it back, I've nullified the changes from `addPoints`.

What's a good way to solve this? I dont want to re-`get` the state after every function call "just in case" that function modified the state. I can switch to always using `modify` instead of `get` and `put` but that makes my code awkward.

Comment: Why does using `modify` instead of `get`/`put` make your code akward? It is the correct solution here

Comment: When you perform `state <- get`, you're getting the state at a specific point in the execution.  You then perform `addPoints`, which modifies the state that's stored in the monad (not `state` from the first line).  The design of the library is to work this way, you have to get the current state before doing anything with it, otherwise your state will be out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for atomic/transactional modifications to the state—that's pretty much exactly what `modify` provides. It's not possible to "slip" some state modifying operation between the `get` and the `put` with `modify`. If you don't use it you'll have to manage the complexity of ensuring that nothing happens between `get` and `put`.